# Angular priority of directives not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive that removes unwanted elements from a list, repeated by an `ng-repeat`.

However i have a hard time getting the *priority* working, by default i know the ng-repeat that repeats my wanted and unwanted elements is 100, so in my directive i set restriction to a value below that so ensure ng-repeats has finished before looking for unwanted elements.

This is (still) not working :

```
myApp.directive('imageContainerRemoval', function() {
 return {
  priority: 999,
  restrict: 'E',
  link: function postLink (scope, element, attrs) {
```

Comment: And how are you removing items? Put missing code. And also post HTML code with directive.

Comment: ng-repeat priority is 1000 not 0. Also not sure if setting priority as negative number is valid...

Answer (score 0):

From [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-):

> Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, **but post-link
>   functions are run in reverse order**. The order of directives with the
>   same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

As the `link` function is just a shortcut for the `post-link` function, I guess instead you have to use the `pre-link` function or reverse the priorities.

**NOTE:** The priority of ngRepeat is 1000 by default.

Comment: What happens when you choose a priority >1000?

Comment: prio > 1000  my directive fires before the ng-repeat has finished rendering.
prio < 1000 my directive never fires.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36742428/angular-directive-priority for updated question with more info.