# angular directive priority

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive that removes a section of divs if ALL of them are empty. (expected to be an image inside)

i know that ng-repeat default priority is 1000, and that the higher values gets compiled first, so i sat the priority of the directive to be below that.

**The directive:**

```
myApp.directive('imageContainerRemoval', function() {
 return {
  priority: 999,
  restrict: 'E',
  link: function postLink (scope, element, attrs) {
   var watchGroup = attrs.imageContainerRemoval,
       sectionGotImage = false;

    // ** WORK AROUND FOR PRIORITY! **
    // 0 milisec delay to ensure ng-style is applied and ng-repeat has finished.
    setTimeout(function() {
    var elementsInClass = element.find('div[image-container-removal="' + watchGroup + '"]');

    // Check for images in section.
    if (elementsInClass.children().context.children.length > 0) {
      sectionGotImage = true;
    }

    // If there's no images in section, delete all image container divs.
    if (!sectionGotImage) {
      $(elementsInClass.children().context).remove();
      sectionGotImage = false;
    }
   }, 0);
  }
 };
});
```

**usage:**

```
<div class="imageContainer" image-container-removal="chart-{{Id}}">
<img class="thumbnailIMG" ng-src="{{::data.image}}" ng-if="data.image != null" />
</div>
```

it works, but it really annoys me that the priority is not working, and that i have to do this timeout hack to make it work. Am i missing something ?

Comment: you should use $timeout inspite of setTimeOut function. and also set priority much lesser like  priority: -400

Comment: @ShailendraSinghDeol tried using $timeout. but i get ' timeout not a function ' error in browser, - im using it the exact same way, and remembered to add it to the links args. No idea why its not working for me.

Comment: inject $timeout in your directive like as myApp.directive('imageContainerRemoval',['$timeout', function($timeout)